# How to check whether a file is serial or partitioned using abinitio functions only

Tags: ab-initio

I need to resolve a parameter value depending upon whether I have a serial or multifile. Below is the scenario...

I have created a generic graph where I have a reformat component just after the input file component... At run time!  I need to check input file if it is serial or multi...  And accordingly I have to populate the layout of reformat...!

Hence..  To achieve this I am looking for some specific abinitio function...!

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit the question to give more detail about what you are trying to do? Not much to go on so far.

Comment: it is somewhat better.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a function - `m_fs_check`.

You can use this function in the graph parameters and use the resolved value as a condition to determine the layout.

Answer (score 0):

`m_fs_check` will check if the directory is a serial or multi directory. However a user can still create a serial file on a multi directory. One option is fire a `m_ls -lt` command. Result displays a flag 'M' which denotes that a file is multi file. For serial files this flag remains blank.

Answer (score 0):

Use `m_expand($INPUT_FILE_PATH)` in PDL at PSET level to identify directory depth. if depth is greater than one then its multifile else serial.then use output flag  into your reformat.